# Разделение столбцов в таблице синонимов меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, синонимы-меток, дизайн

В таблице [синонимов меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) требуется разделить заголовки последних двух столбцов:

[image: синонимы меток]

[Tx:4212](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266144?key=9c2485a66f064c8690e791958c4d36ae)

> Renames

[Tx:4215](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266145?key=d55b30607c2a9a2616347d6edb789f6b)

> Last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут проблема в том, что строка не входит в фиксированную ширину столбца. Поскольку при использовании метки-синонимами она фактически заменяется на основную, можно заменить предпоследний заголовок:

> Автор
>   **Замен**
>   Последняя

---

Только что применил переводы:

> Замен
>   Последняя

Comment: Вариантов решения подобных проблем локализации всегда будет как минимум два: 1. Впихнуть перевод в ширину оригинального текста; 2. Растянуть размер под локализованный термин. Первое проще для фикса, второе - универсальнее.

Comment: @alexolut если хотите второй вариант - лучше отдельным предложением опубликовать.

Comment: почему-то вместо `замен` я вижу `имена`

Comment: Да, был такой перевод. Я подумал, что этот вариант не очень подходит.

Comment: когда он успел? О_о

Comment: Этот перевод был применён 15 часов назад. У вас всё ещё нет учётки в транзифексе? )

Comment: учетка есть, на iPad просто transifex ужасно работает, ничерта не видно.